# PHPMailer to use Gmail as SMTP server.Could not connect to SMTP host. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

i am trying to use phpMailer to send confirmation messages to users via email. my code is this:

```
<?php
include("class.phpmailer.php");
include("class.smtp.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); // set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 465; // set the port to use
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "sender@gmail.com"; // your SMTP username or your gmail username
$mail->Password = "mypasswrord"; // your SMTP password or your gmail password
$from = "webmaster@example.com"; // Reply to this email
$to="receiver@yahoo.com"; // Recipients email ID
$name="Jersey Name"; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = "Webmaster"; // Name to indicate where the email came from when the recepient received
$mail->AddAddress($to,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($from,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "Sending Email From Php Using Gmail";
$mail->Body = "This Email Send through phpmailer, This is the HTML BODY "; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = "This is the body when user views in plain text format"; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

i already enabled ssl in php.ini.

PS> sender@gmail.com is a mask email to protect the privacy. but i did put a true email address in that part

Comment: have you considered using http://swiftmailer.org/ ? It works out of the box for sending emails via GMail. Great library! :-)

Comment: Also, change host from "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" to "smtp.gmail.com"

Comment: nothing happened at all.. not even an echo

Comment: jamie can you send me a simple example code that uses swiftmailer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail

Answer (score 18, accepted):

in you php.ini make sure you have uncommented the line with

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: this is only for windows...where is for linux

Comment: For Linux: extension=php_openssl.so

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://webomania.wordpress.com/2007/06/12/getting-phpmailer-to-connect-to-gmails-smtp-server/) 

2) Comment out the following lines of code in class.phpmailer.php

```php
/*
if(strstr($hosts[$index], ":"))
list($host, $port) = explode(":",
$hosts[$index]); else 
*/
```

Try this if you haven't already.

Comment: that line does not exist in my class.phpmailer.php

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://serversideguy.com/2010/01/14/how-to-send-an-email-using-phpmailer-and-gmail-for-smtp/) has code the author claims "worked flawlessly".

The only real difference I see between his and yours is that his has:

```
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
```

I guess I would start with his code exactly to see if it works, and then debug from there.

Comment: So his code works for him but not for you?  Then there is something different in the environment...  Try `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465` to make sure it is not a firewall issue.  Next most likely cause is a failure to validate the server's SSL cert.

Answer (score 0):

**wrong:**

```
$mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server
```

**good:**

```
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // specify main and backup server
```

Comment: This did not work for me. It only works with the "ssl://" included.