# smtp error while setting up phpmailer

Tags: phpmailer

i'm having difficulty setting up phpmailer on my local web server and would appreciate any help

i am running xamppp 1.7.4 and php 5.3.5 - i keep receiving the following error message whenever trying to send mail

> ```
> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
> ```

here is the code i am using right now

```
require("resources/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");
    //send the email with an email containing the activation link to the supplied email address

   $mailer = new PHPMailer();
   $mailer->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
   $mailer->Mailer = "smtp";
   $mailer->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
   $mailer->Port = 587;
   $mailer->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
   $mailer->Username = $email_kite;
   $mailer->Password = $emailpass_kite;
   $mailer->From = $email_kite;
   $mailer->FromName = 'Kite';
   $mailer->Body = 'Testing';
   $mailer->Subject = 'Get started with Kite';
   $mailer->AddAddress($email);
   if(!$mailer->Send())
   {
       // message not sent
  echo '<p class="c7">Unfortunately the <b>activation</b> email could not be sent and user registration has failed. Please go <a href="register.php">back</a> and try again.</p>';
      echo '<br><img src="resources/img/spacer.gif" alt="" width="1" height="10">';
  include_once ("resources/php/footer.php");
  exit;
   }
   else
   {
       // message sent
       "Email sent successfully!";
   }
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168882/resolved-phpmailer-to-use-gmail-as-smtp-server-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host ?

Comment: No, I don't think it is.  If the dll wasn't being loaded, I don't think it would be generating that message.  I really think it's the port.  Even if the dll isn't being loaded, that's definitely going to keep it from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
$mailer->Port = 465;
```

Port 587 is for TLS, the SSL port is 465.

Comment: Instead of falling back to the obsolete and deprecated SSL mechanism, how about making the TLS approach work?

    $mailer->Port = 587;
    $mailer->Host = "tls://smtp.gmail.com";