# Can you send emails from localhost with PHPmailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I tried this, but I get "ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?"

```
$mail = new \PHPMailer(true); 

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username   = "xctgrlx420@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "wr^#@f9h@)(f";

$mail->AddAddress('contact@mywebsite.com', 'John Doe');
$mail->SetFrom('me@me.com', 'First Last');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), advanced';
$mail->MsgHTML('Add some HTML here');
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168882/phpmailer-to-use-gmail-as-smtp-server-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-mailer-err

Comment: sorry I enabled that extension and it works thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple google search revealed this forum - http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-ssl-667689.html

And I guess the problem is that you need "[OpenSSL extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.setup.php)".