# PHPmailer SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm getting this when trying to send an email.

```
Connection: opening to smtp.163.com:25, t=300, opt=array ()
Connection: opened
SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 163.com Anti-spam GT for Coremail System (163com[20141201])
CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-mail250-PIPELINING250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN250-AUTH=LOGIN PLAIN250-coremail 1Uxr2xKj7kG0xkI17xGrU7I0s8FY2U3Uj8Cz28x1UUUUU7Ic2I0Y2Ur83fsGUCa0xDrUUUUj250-STARTTLS250 8BITMIME
CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 dXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: xxx
SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: xxx=
CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 221 Bye
Connection: closed<br>
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

Code :

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mydomain.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "user@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxxxx";

$mail->setFrom('user@xxx.com', 'user');
$mail->addAddress('user@xxx.com', 'user');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP test';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Comment: Where is `$mail->SMTPSecure` ?

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting with service providers like godaddy, it wont allow you to use SMTP authentication.Kindly check through.
If not, you need to check  your port address.
Try with google smtp in your localhost first.

Comment: I have tried google smtp, it works like a charm with SMTPAuth = true, ssl 465.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496650/smtp-connect-failed-message-was-not-sent-mailer-error-smtp-connect-failed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using a RFC ignorant mail software. Right here, the server is prompting the client for the username:

`SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 334 dXNlcm5hbWU6`

Except it's doing it wrong. It's supposed to send a 334 code followed by the base64 encoded value of: `Username:`, which is `VXNlcm5hbWU6`.

Instead, it's sending the base64 encoded value of `username:`, which is `dXNlcm5hbWU6`. Note the lower cased `u`. Thus, PHPMailer never sees an appropriate SMTP AUTH prompt and the authentication fails.