# Getting error SMTP connect() failed phpmailer with localhost

Tags: php, email

I'm getting error SMTP connect() failed phpmailer with localhost:

> 2015-09-10 09:34:48   Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:587,
>   timeout=300, options=array ( ) 2015-09-10 09:34:48    SMTP ERROR: Failed
>   to connect to server: (0) 2015-09-10 09:34:48 SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message
>   could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

1. Is it phpmailer cannot run at localhost?
2. If  I want really run at localhost how can I change the code?
3. I tried using mailto function is work for me but I want change whole thing.
4. can give any suggestion. I really want to learn it.

   This is the code from github:
          require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

   ```
      $mail = new PHPMailer;

      //$mail->SMTPDebug = 4;                               // Enable verbose debug output

      $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
       $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
      $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Username = 'mygmail@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
      $mail->Password = 'mygmailpassword';                           // SMTP password
      $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
      $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to
      //$mail->Host = 'tls://smtp.gmail.com:587';

      $mail->From = 'ikramlim@gmail.com';
      $mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
      $mail->addAddress('ikramlim@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient

      $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

      $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
      $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

       if(!$mail->send()) {
          echo 'Message could not be sent.';
          echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       } else {
         echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
   ```

Comment: Can you share the code that might have to be changed? So far, you only posted the error message, as far as I can see.

Comment: this is the code I copy from github. I did changed sendmail.ini and php.ini file but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer is normally working on all systems.

I think you have an old openssl extension or your extension is not enabled. Check that with a `phpinfo()` if there is openssl enabled.

If not then enable it in your `php.ini`.

And the other way is that it seems that Google has some problems. When i try to send an Email at the moment i have connection problems with Thunderbird, too. I have to try it some times to connect to gmail.

Comment: sorry I still newbes here.. how I can enable phpinfo(). where I can find it? sorry

Comment: i did changed the the setting in gmail like this: https://i.gyazo.com/57caeeb9fab1ce7d832b6005dcc03524.png

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that please try using 'tls' with port 587 instead of 'ssl' with port 587.

Also check whether you are including class.phpmailer.php(ie: require 'class.phpmailer.php';) , If you are doing please comment it and give a try.

Comment: still getting error too changed port 465 to 587, and require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

Comment: Please try giving this as tls instead of ssl.
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

Comment: Try going through this post . check whether it helps for you .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496650/smtp-connect-failed-message-was-not-sent-mailer-error-smtp-connect-failed

Comment: Hi @Murali thanks alot.. I solved this problem. Thank you so much