# Issues send emails in localhost but not in liveserver

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an issue with PHPMailer. 
First i have integrated phpmailer and email are sent without any issues in localhost and live server. Since yesterday, i have an issues to send email in localhost but not in live server. The error i got when i send the email in localhost are

> Email could not be sent to the recently approved member. ErrorSMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

This is the same code to send the emails both in live server and localhost.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'someone@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = $pw;                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 25;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('someone@gmail.com', 'Reboot E-Magazine');
$mail->addAddress($email);     // Add a recipient
$mail->Subject = 'Article Confirmation';
$mail->Body =
'Reboot Magazine
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your article was not been approved due to certain reasons.
Please ensure the article are well-written and relevant to the topic.
--------------------------------------------------------------------

Sincerely,
Riyaz Ahmad
Admin of Reboot E-magazine';

if(!$mail->send())
{
    $error = "Email could not be sent. Error". $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    $msg = "Email has been sent to notify the member";
}
```

Comment: Have you read the troubleshooting article you linked to? It has some good advice and even things to check that your code is clearly guilty of

Answer (score 1):

I believe it was already answered here:

[SMTP Connect() failed. Message was not sent.Mailer error: SMTP Connect() failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496650/smtp-connect-failed-message-was-not-sent-mailer-error-smtp-connect-failed)

Commenting

> $mail->isSMTP();

usualy fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks. Now working fine with localhost. But are there any issues commenting that part in live server?

Comment: No worries. You shouldn't have any issues with that.

Comment: i just found out that email are not sent to the particular user. Do i need to change the port number or the tls encryption?

Comment: thanks btw, i have uncomment the smtp part and change the port number to 587 and it works fine.. thanks for your help