# PHPMailer can't connect to Gmail

Tags: php, bash, email, gmail, phpmailer

So I've been scouring the web on this issue, and almost every example was condemned as a firewall or server related problem.  From what I can tell, my server is connecting just fine to gmail, but PHPMailer still fails to connect.  Here is my PHP:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");        
$host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "587";
$checkconn = fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 5);
if(!$checkconn){
    echo "($errno) $errstr";
} else {
    echo 'Connected through fsocketopen.<br />';
}

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "********";
$mail->Port = "587";
```

The credentials are not shown, but are 100% correct.  Here are the results:

> Connected through fsocketopen.
> Mailer Error: SMTP Connect()
>   failed.

As you can see, the server is allowing a connection to gmail through fsocketopen, but PHPMailer will not connect.  I've even accessed my server through SSH, and received the following response:

> -bash-4.1$ telnet smtp.gmail.com 587
>       Trying 2607:f8b0:400d:c02::6d...
>       Connected to smtp.gmail.com.
>       Escape character is '^]'.
>       220 mx.google.com ESMTP g1sm52568728qec.9 - gsmtp

So two tests verify connection between my server and Gmail is available.  So now I'm left to assume that there is a problem with my PHPMailer.  I've scanned through the class.phpmailer.php file, but I just don't know enough about it to see where there would be a problem.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168882/phpmailer-to-use-gmail-as-smtp-server-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host-mailer-err

Comment: I have read that already.  The primary solution in that example was making sure extension=php_openssl.dll was active in the php.ini file.  This has been done.  Again, the server itself is not having a problem connecting, just PHPMailer.

Answer (score 2):

I reckon this is the problem:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
```

you try to use SSL, yet in your telnet example, you don't. You should use port 465 for secure SMTP, or disable `SMTPSecure`.

(Note SMTPAuth and SMTPSecure are different concepts. SMTPAuth makes sure you are that you say you are. SMTPSecure encrypts the communication channel.)

**Update**, this code tested and works. I also tried the non-SSL'ed version, but it seems Google doesn't allow plaintext SMTP anymore.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
$mail->Username = "sender@example.com";       
$mail->Password = "******";
$mail->Port = 465;                // note the ommission of quotes

$mail->AddAddress("receiver@example.com");

$mail->Subject = "test";
$mail->MsgHTML("<b>test</b>");
$mail->Send();
```

If it doesn't, you might have some firewalling enabled.

Comment: I tried changing the port to 465 for all connections attempted in my original post, with the same results.

Comment: And what if you remove the `$smtp->SMTPSecure` ?

Comment: Nothing has changed.  The fsockopen connects through port 465, but PHPMailer fails to connect.

Comment: Do not use `SMTPSecure` and connect on port 587, then you will be the same as your telnet example.

Comment: I have already attempted using that exact code, with no success.  The only difference I noticed in this example was that it defined $mail->Host twice, and it requested a different smtp server with the first definition.  This is the only example I've found that does this.

Comment: I do get a different error code with this example - just more detailed: SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)SMTP Connect() failed.

Comment: So your example did not work for me.  And this goes back to my original question.  How can I connect via SSH or fsockopen if there is a firewall issue?

Comment: @user2709974 you can use `openssl` to test SSL links in a telnet-kind of way. It should be available on any Linux distro and the manual can help you out.

Comment: I found the answer.  It won't let me post it yet, so I will do so when I can.  It ended up being a problem with the PHPMailer script.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears as though the PHPMailer Script I had installed on the server was not able to handle third party relays - well at least not this one.  I had already tried uploading the latest version of class.phpmailer.php, but in this case, I downloaded the entire package from SourceForge and reuploaded all files to the server.  This did the trick.  Lesson learned!