# phpmailer smtp error while using in online server

Tags: php, html, server, phpmailer

This is my code... this was working correctly if I use this on local server but when I use this on my server online I am getting this error:

> Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

You can also see by going to this link : http://khalsasewak.com/mail/

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = '******@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '******';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('raman.singh9718@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Comment: try $mail->Port = 465;

Comment: try removing or commenting out `$mail->isSMTP();`

Comment: Sunil Rajput  should be right "Port 465 (SSL required)" read this https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en...

Comment: It might sound a little radical, but you could take a wild leap into the unknown and read the docs that the error message points you at, which happens to answer this exact question in great detail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPMailer can't connect to Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828008/phpmailer-cant-connect-to-gmail)

Comment: Should i have to do some settings in my hosting?

Comment: @RamandeepSingh: Either change `$mail->Port = 587;` to `$mail->Post = 465;` or leave it as it is and change `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` to `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` instead.

Comment: i'll changed it but still i am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Use port 465 for `SMTPSecure = 'ssl'` or port 587 for `SMTPSecure = 'tls';`