# PHP: cannot send sms, but can send regular old email

Tags: php, email, sms

I am trying to send text messages to my phone from my server using php. I recently configured the server to send email, which it does (verified). It, however, goes into my spam box. When I try to send a message via sms I do not receive anything.

This is the script I am using:

```
$to = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";
$subject = "testing";
$body = "";
$headers = 'From: testemailaddress@gmail.com';

if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>"); 
} else {
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

The address that I am using for sms is myphonenumber@txt.att.net in the 'To' field.

I am going to go out on a limb here and say this is a authentication issue, maybe.

Is there anything I need to configure further? (i.e. php.ini)

Comment: can you send a sms to that address using your regular email client? email to txt gateways work in a variety of ways, you should check the docs of the host.

Comment: Had the same problem a while ago. It most likely goes to your spambox because you set the From: to ..@gmail.com, while your sending server is something like localhost. try setting the From: to noreply@yourdomain and set an additional "Reply-To:whatever@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most email providers/servers today rely heavily on spam filtering / dnsbl. Your webserver is not a know mail server, and you probably did not set up [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) or anything.

An approach to avoid all those issues would be to utilize a Google Mail address (or any other providers). And instead of the PHP mail function use something more complex like [`Swiftmailer`](http://www.google.com/search?q=Swiftmailer), which generates Mail headers that are less commonly autoclassified as spam.

See also: [Using php's swiftmailer with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail)

Comment: This is what I figured was going on. Not a big deal as long as I can route it trough gmail. First, I'll give Swiftmailer a try.

Comment: I tried swiftmailer, but could not get it to work. Then, after trying to delete the /var/www/lib/ folder, I accidentally deleted the /lib folder and had to reinstall the whole server.

Comment: Sorry to hear. If Swiftmailer does not work that easily (it's a matter of configuration), then try PEAR Mail. This has similar capabilities.