# How can I use my GMAIL account to send out emails using PHP?

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, sendmail

After searching for days on how to do this I came across this question:
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

Seems like exactly what I have been trying to achieve but I have had no success, maybe it's because I don't know how to do the HTML to work with this code?

for testing purposes I tried the code on the top voted question on the link I pasted and
made a button that when you click it, it would go to the PHP file (No success).

Comment: It's too vague user519753. What is the errors ? See your HTTP server los.

Comment: @sputnik user Panique just suggested that I use PHPMailer, all in all It's the same issue I'm getting not matter what technique I'm using; the page will be blank or display the code in firefox and nothing will execute when I go to localhost/send.php

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with PHP only, because `mail()` doesn't support authentication. You have to use a mailing library.
I recommend [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) which is easy to use, supports many features (authentication, sending HTML mails, attachments, etc.), and is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to send over tsl/ssl which is why your mail function is not working.

Solution with tsl/ssl already exists here: [Using php's swiftmailer with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://neo22s.com/send-email-using-gmail-and-php/ and http://webcodingeasy.com/PHP-API039s/Send-email-from-Gmail-using-PHP

Comment: When I use the one on neo22s.com this is what happens: I copy paste the text into notepad, type in my gmail information, I save it as send.php and then I go to localhost/send.php and then I get to see the code displayed in Firefox, no execution happens