# Error message when using SwiftMailer with Laravel

Tags: smtp, laravel, gmail, laravel-4, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send emails (Gmail) using the built in SwiftMailer bundle with Laravel 4. I've successfully been able to send and receive emails on my local server, when live, I keep receiving this error message:

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "info@myemail.com" using 2 possible authenticators
```

**controller (show_sent method)**

```
public function show_sent() {

    $name = Input::get('name', 'someone');
    $email = Input::get('email');
    
    // I'm creating an array with user's info but most likely you can use $user->email or pass $user object to closure later
    $user = array(
        'email'=>'info@myemail.com',
        'name'=> $name
    );
     
    // the data that will be passed into the mail view blade template
    $data = array(
        'detail'=>'Visitor\'s website enquiry',
        'name'  => $user['name'],
        'email'=> $email
    );
     
    // use Mail::send function to send email passing the data and using the $user variable in the Closure
    Mail::send('emails.registration', $data, function($message) use ($user)
    {
      $message->from('info@myemail.com', 'someone');
      $message->to($user['email'], $user['name'])->subject('New Site Registration');
    });

    $view = View::make('sent');
    $view->title = 'Sent';
    $view->keywords = 'to complete'; 
    $view->description = 'to complete';
$view->body_id = 'sent-page';
    return $view;       
}
```

**mail.php settings:**

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
'port' => 465,
'encryption' => 'ssl',
```

I've tried using a few other gmail accounts, all had the same error message.
Any help would be fantastic, thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663783/php-fatal-error-swift-transportexception-with-message-failed-to-authenticate