# How to send an email with $_POST data submitted with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, email

I want to submit some data from localStorage to

```
Autoform.submitStoredData = function() {
    var data = localStorage.tbRecoveredData;
    if(data) {
        jQuery.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url:"http://www.thewebsite.com/Autoform.php",
            data: data,
            success: function() {
                console.log("success");
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,error) {
                console.log("payload failed to submit with xhr: " + xhr + ", status: " + status + ", and error: " + error);
            }
        });
        localStorage.removeItem("tbRecoveredData");
    }
};
```

I am getting "success" in the console so far so good. Autoform PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        $data = $_POST;
        mail('myemail@gmail.com', 'OK SO here at least is the captured string', $data);
    }

?>
```

This does nothing or at least no email gets sent. I admit I dont know much about PHP, I've tried googling without much luck. Do I need to wrap this in a sort of self invoking function or something because it seems like the PHP code is not being executed. Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Can you check what's happening by putting `var_dump(mail(...))` and tell us the result? Looks like `mail()` is not correctly configured.

Comment: does var_dump log something somewhere? I did as you said but dont know where to look for the result

Comment: You need to check your output. Don't try it in your current implementation. Use a new `.php` file and try testing out if your mail function returns true or fals.e

Comment: ok ill try that

Comment: It returns NULL - so I'm sure thats the problem now how to fix - some config then?

Comment: Yes, your server isn't configured correctly with `mail()` function. Either you need to contact the server provider or you need to [fix it yourself](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable).

Comment: OK I can figure it out from here then... if you put want to this as the answer I will accept if not I'll delete question - I thought mail() was a standard php function - didn't know I had to configure

Comment: The Quack It article seems to be excellent in this case. Have a look and let me know if you need further guidance in setting it up. I have done it in almost a variety of servers and it worked.

Comment: Sure I have a VPS - I'm sure I can do it but I sure appreciate the help.

Comment: Anytime. You can find my email address(es) in my profile. Just give me a shout if something's necessary...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, if you try putting the below code and finding it to be `NULL`:

```
var_dump(mail(...));
```

Then you need to configure your server to make the PHP work with it's built in `mail()` function. There are several ways to do it:

- [PHP `mail()` function enable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable)
- [PHP Mail Configuration](http://www.quackit.com/php/tutorial/php_mail_configuration.cfm)
- [How to configure PHP to send e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533863/how-to-configure-php-to-send-e-mail)

Answer (score 0):

If you want send a email you by function mail(). you must set the configuration. like the answer above. So I suggest you send your email by SMTP. It's easy to send without configuration. You just need to register a private email such as Email or Yahoo.

[From this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server)

> ```
>   // Pear Mail Library    require_once "Mail.php";
>
>   $from = '<your@mail.com>'; //change this to your email address  $to =
> '<someone@mail.com>'; // change to address    $subject = 'Insert subject
> here'; // subject of mail     $body = "Hello world! this is the content
> of the email"; //content of mail
>
>   $headers = array(
>       'From' => $from,
>       'To' => $to,
>       'Subject' => $subject   );
>
>
>   $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
>           'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
>           'port' => '465',
>           'auth' => true,
>           'username' => 'your@gmail.com', //your gmail account
>           'password' => 'snip' // your password
>       ));
>
>     // Send the mail  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
> ```