# mail.php script not working for subscribe and contact page

Tags: php, email, smtp, sendmail, google-apps

My web developer made this script to send notifications to people subscribing to my mailing list and the people who contact me, through the form on my website
The problem is, the recipients are not able to receive the emails, and I am not able to receive the notification on my mail id about a new subscriber or a contact

*Sender id - notifications@llaveshagarwal.com*

**Moreover, the same script works on his server (which we used for testing) but doesn't work on my server**

Is there a problem with my SMTP server settings ? 
Also, I am using Google Apps for Gmail 
Here is his script

What should I do ?

```
<?php
if($_POST['type'] == "subscribe") {

/*$to = "notifications@llaveshagarwal.com";
    $subject = "New Email Subscriber";
    $txt = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\nFrom: ".$_POST['from'];
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['from'];

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    $to = $_POST['from'];
    $subject = "Thank you for subscribing with us.";
    $txt = "Hey ".$_POST['name']." ,\r\nGreetings from LLavesh Agarwal Textile Agency\r\nThank you for subscribing with us for Exclusive and Latest Catalogs and product launches.\r\nWe will update you soon.\r\n\r\nRegards,\r\nTeam LLavesh Agarwal\r\n\r\n*This is an automated Email. Please do not reply to this Email id. If you wish to talk to us, kindly Email us at hello@llaveshagarwal.com";
    $headers = "From: notifications@llaveshagarwal.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);*/

    $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'llavesha_admin', 'Admin@1234');
    $db= mysql_select_db('llavesha_contact_system', $link);

    $insert='insert into subscribe (name,email) values ("'.$_POST["name"].'","'.$_POST["from"].'")';
    if(mysql_query($insert)) {
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "fail";
    }
}

elseif($_POST['type'] == "contact") {
    $to = "notifications@llaveshagarwal.com";
    $subject = "New Contact";
    $txt = "Name: ".$_POST['name']."\r\nContact: ".$_POST['mobile']."\r\nCategory: ".$_POST['bussiness_type']."\r\nDescription: ".$_POST['project_detail'];
    $headers = "From: ".$_POST['from'];

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    $to = $_POST['from'];
    $subject = "Thank you for contacting us.";
    $txt = "Hey ".$_POST['name']." ,\r\nGreetings from LLavesh Agarwal Textile Agency\r\nThank you for contacting us.\r\nWe will update you soon !\r\n\r\nRegards,\r\nTeam LLavesh Agarwal\r\n\r\n*This is an automated Email. Please do not reply to this Email id. If you wish to talk to us, kindly Email us at hello@llaveshagarwal.com";
    $headers = "From: notifications@llaveshagarwal.com";

    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);

    echo "success";
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on windows (wamp)? Have you enabling php sendmail on php.ini? read: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

or you can read: [php mail() function on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342822/php-mail-function-on-localhost)

If you want to make it simpler, use phpmailer instead: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

How to use it by @pooria: [How to configure PHP to send e-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533863/how-to-configure-php-to-send-e-mail)

```
require('./PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail=new PHPMailer();
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

$body = 'This is the message';

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';

$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

$mail->Username   = 'me.sender@gmail.com';
$mail->Password   = '123!@#';

$mail->SetFrom('me.sender@gmail.com', $name);
$mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@mycomp.com','no-reply');
$mail->Subject    = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAddress('abc1@gmail.com', 'title1');
$mail->AddAddress('abc2@gmail.com', 'title2'); /* ... */

$mail->AddAttachment($fileName);
$mail->send();
```

Comment: I am using Cpanel/WHM and not localhost

Comment: have you ask your host support and ask if php mail is enabled?