# swiftmailer send email using gmail with custom domain

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

In symfony2.3 I am using swiftmailer.

I have a Google Apps address like myname@abc.com and my normal gmail address myname@gmail.com

When using:

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_encryption: ssl
auth_mode:         login
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user:       myname
mailer_password:   pymass
```

the configuration works great and it sends emails from my gmail address but using myname@abc.com as mailer_user with correct password doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration for sending from (what I assume is) a Google Apps account differs from a Gmail account. Your swiftmailer parameters should look something like this:

```
mailer_transport:  smtp
mailer_host:       smtp.gmail.com
mailer_user:       myname@abc.com
mailer_password:   pymass
auth_mode:         login
port:              587
encryption:        tls
```

Make sure to include your entire email address as well as the port and encryption protocol.

I derived the solution from [this article](http://nuclearprojects.com/blog/setting-up-swift-mailer-to-send-through-google-apps-smtp-servers/) a few months back.

Also, a small note: its `encryption` not `mailer_encyption`. You can read more about the swiftmailer parameters for Symfony [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html).

Answer (score 0):

When you create the message in your controller or anywhere, it's there where you put the sender (setFrom method)

```
// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('john@doe.com' => 'John Doe'))
  ->setTo(array('receiver@domain.org', 'other@domain.org' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Here is the message itself')
;
```

In your configuration file the mailer_user is used only for connecting to the gmail's smtp server.