# Swift Mime Headers Unstructured Header not found in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2.3

I am using Swift Mailer in Symfony 2.3.7. I am getting error for it.

I used the following code:

Config.yml

```
  swiftmailer:
     transport:  gmail
     host:       null
     username:   [email]
     password:   [password]
```

Controller code

```
use Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle;
```

And then in action

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Hello Email')
    ->setFrom('send@example.com')
    ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
    ->setBody(
        "Hello"
    );
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

When I passing the route of this action in the URl then its giving me error

> ### FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Swift_Mime_Headers_UnstructuredHeader' not found in /var/www/html/edubolderp/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/SimpleHeaderFactory.php line 95

Comment: why host is null? look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17970096/swiftmailer-send-email-using-gmail-with-custom-domain

Comment: I also tried with **smtp.gmail.com** but no success

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that you need to specify the mime type of mail
add the mime type in body 
replace `"Hello"` by `"Hello",'text/html'`

[see docs for more details](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html)