# Not able to send mail from test website yii2 swiftmailer

Tags: linux, yii2, swiftmailer

my server is linux based. please helpme with the proper mailer config

```
'mailer' => [
            'class'            => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath'         => '@common/mail',

            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',              
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using php's swiftmailer with gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478906/using-phps-swiftmailer-with-gmail)

Answer (score 0):

for gmail should be  port `587` encryption `tls`

```
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'username' => 'your.username@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'yourpassword',
            'port' => '587',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
```

Comment: getting error: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at535 5.7.8https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials r71-v6sm1617332pfg.43 - gsmtp"

Comment: the server is responding:  but seems you have problem  with your credential  ..check better